# Flutter : how to make container height wrap around its content

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, containers

I am making alert notification and I want the container to be wrapped around it content. Was not able to give left border to the rounded container to had to make another container that will be matching the height of the parent container. Now if i give height to the parent container this doesn't seems to be a good approach as the text inside the container might vary... I want the container to automatically detect the height necessary for the nice appearance and widgets inside it do not overlap or exceed
[image]

```
 Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: 80.0,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
                          borderRadius:  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                                spreadRadius: 0,
                                blurRadius: 1,
                                offset: const Offset(0, 1)
                            ), // no shadow color set, defaults to black
                          ]
                      ),
                      child: Row(
                         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 8,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),bottomLeft:Radius.circular(10.0) ),
                                    color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 40,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Row(

                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children:[

                                      Expanded(
                                        flex: 1,
                                        child: Text(
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                                          String.fromCharCode( CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.codePoint),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            inherit: false,
                                            color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)).shade400,
                                            fontSize: 40.0,
                                            fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.fontFamily,
                                            package: CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.fontPackage,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(
                                        flex:5,
                                        child: Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0,right: 0.0),
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Text(

                                                  "Success",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    inherit: false,
                                                    color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)).shade400,
                                                    fontSize: 16.0,

                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                Text(

                                                  "lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                                    inherit: false,
                                                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                                                    fontSize: 14.0,

                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            )
                                        ),
                                      ),

                                    ]
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 5,
                                child: Container(
                                  child: IconButton(
                                      onPressed: (){},
                                      icon: Icon(
                                        Icons.close_rounded,
                                        color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)).shade400,
                                        size: 16.0,
                                      ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )

    ],
                            )
                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            child:Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 80.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  border: Border(
                    left: BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    top: BorderSide.none,
                    right: BorderSide.none,
                    bottom: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      spreadRadius: 0,
                      blurRadius: 1,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 1),
                    ), // no shadow color set, defaults to black
                  ],
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 40,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled,
                              color:
                                  (const Color(0xFF70AD47)).withAlpha(400),
                              size: 40.0,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              // flex: 5,
                              child: Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 10.0, right: 0.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Success",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          inherit: false,
                                          color: (const Color(0xFF70AD47))
                                              .withAlpha(400),
                                          fontSize: 16.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          "lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                            inherit: false,
                                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                                .colorScheme
                                                .onPrimaryContainer,
                                            fontSize: 14.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 5,
                      child: Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.close_rounded,
                            color: (const Color(0xFF70AD47)).withAlpha(200),
                            size: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          )
```

and you get results like this i tripled the text and checkout the result also i removed container for border and created the left border with border property of container :
[image]

**EDIT:**
try this code in this the container will grow according to the text:

```
ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                // height: 80.0,

                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  border: Border(
                    left: BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    top: BorderSide.none,
                    right: BorderSide.none,
                    bottom: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      spreadRadius: 0,
                      blurRadius: 1,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 1),
                    ), // no shadow color set, defaults to black
                  ],
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 40,
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled,
                              color:
                                  (const Color(0xFF70AD47)).withAlpha(400),
                              size: 40.0,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              // flex: 5,
                              child: Container(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 0.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      "Success",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        inherit: false,
                                        color: (const Color(0xFF70AD47))
                                            .withAlpha(400),
                                        fontSize: 16.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                                        inherit: false,
                                        color: Theme.of(context)
                                            .colorScheme
                                            .onPrimaryContainer,
                                        fontSize: 14.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 5,
                      child: Container(
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {},
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.close_rounded,
                            color: (const Color(0xFF70AD47)).withAlpha(200),
                            size: 16.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
          )
```

this is the result:

[image]

Comment: This has one problem.... the detail text is cutting off and beacuse of this  'overflow: TextOverflow.clip,` this does not shows up

Comment: you can change the TextOverflow. values and check which one meets your requirements ellipses will display ... for the extra text and  fade will fade the extra text.

Comment: check the answer i updated it and now the container will grow with  the text

Comment: Yes Now the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the height property and  wrap the parent Container widget with an Expanded widget.it should look like this:
i hope this helps.

```
Expanded( 
        child: Container( width: double.infinity,
      
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
                borderRadius:  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                      spreadRadius: 0,
                      blurRadius: 1,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 1)
                  ), // no shadow color set, defaults to black
                ]
            ),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 8,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),bottomLeft:Radius.circular(10.0) ),
                      color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 40,
                  child: Container(
                    padding:EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(

                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children:[

                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Text(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                              String.fromCharCode( CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.codePoint),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                inherit: false,
                                color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)).shade400,
                                fontSize: 40.0,
                                fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.fontFamily,
                                package: CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.fontPackage,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex:5,
                            child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0,right: 0.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(

                                      "Success",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        inherit: false,
                                        color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)).shade400,
                                        fontSize: 16.0,

                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Text(

                                      "lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                        inherit: false,
                                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                                        fontSize: 14.0,

                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
                            ),
                          ),

                        ]
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Container(
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: (){},
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.close_rounded,
                        color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)).shade400,
                        size: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )

              ],
            )),
      )
```

Comment: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Think you item build like, no need to provide flex. Use expanded to available spaces.

```dart
 Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    buildLeft(context),
    Expanded(child: buildMiddle(context)),

    /// take
    buildRightCloseIcon(),
  ],
),
```

Test widget.

```dart
class FAs23 extends StatefulWidget {
  const FAs23({super.key});

  @override
  State<FAs23> createState() => _FAs23State();
}

class _FAs23State extends State<FAs23> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 80.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                        spreadRadius: 0,
                        blurRadius: 1,
                        offset: const Offset(
                            0, 1)), // no shadow color set, defaults to black
                  ]),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  buildLeft(context),
                  Expanded(child: buildMiddle(context)),

                  /// take
                  buildRightCloseIcon(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildRightCloseIcon() {
    return Container(
      child: IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.close_rounded,
          color: const Color(0xFF70AD47),
          size: 16.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container buildMiddle(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              String.fromCharCode(CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.codePoint),
              style: TextStyle(
                inherit: false,
                color: const Color(0xFF70AD47),
                fontSize: 40.0,
                fontFamily: CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.fontFamily,
                package: CupertinoIcons.check_mark_circled.fontPackage,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 0.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      const Text(
                        "Success",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          inherit: false,
                          color: Color(0xFF70AD47),
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                          inherit: false,
                          color:
                              Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }

  Container buildLeft(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 8,
      // height: double.infinity,// will get parent height
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0), bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
        color: Color(0xFF70AD47),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove     `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

```
Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 8,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),   
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:  BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),bottomLeft:Radius.circular(10.0) ),
                                    color: buildMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF70AD47)),
                                  ),
```

Rest are

```
  Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                blurRadius: 1,
                offset: const Offset(0, 1)),
          ]),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 8,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
              color: Color(0xFF70AD47),
            ),
            child: const SizedBox(height: 100),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Text(
                  "Success",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    inherit: false,
                    color: Color(0xFF70AD47),
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "lorem ipsum de feacto de jure lorem ipsum de feacto de jure",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    inherit: false,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.close_rounded,
              color: Color(0xFF70AD47),
              size: 16.0,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: its just height issue

Comment: You are applying height one of your row child

Comment: Please remove it

Comment: media height is taking full height of screen so you are getting this problem

Comment: the side border is not showing now

Comment: wait checking @hoorIqbal

Comment: Rest are

code you can find whole code there @hoorIqbal

Comment: Also updated screen shot as well @hoorIqbal

Comment: Check rest code

Comment: Have you try this? @hoorIqbal

Comment: yes as the child is 100 of height side border is picking that part and making the container height same height..... if i remove the child same problem